# How to access data from ajax call after the ajax call ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a ajax calls that returns me some data from the server. I work on string function on the data that come from ajax call. From my knowledge i can see the string operation begins before the ajax call gets over. Often giving me undefined error. Here is my ajax call

```
 $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/add_director",
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#addDirModal').modal('hide');
            insertDirector(data); 
        },
        error : function(xhr ,status ,error)
        {
            console.log(xhr);
            alert(xhr);
        }
    });
```

Here is my insertDirector function

```
function insertDirector(data){
      console.log(data);
      if (data.msg == "1") {
        $.each(data,function(key,value){
            var dir_name = value.dir_name;
            var dir_pan = value.dir_pan;
            var dir_din = value.dir_din;
            var dir_addr = value.dir_addr;
            var dir_id = value.id;
            var dir_img = value.dir_img;

              if (dir_name.val().length > 15) {
                var dir_r_name = dir_name.substr(0,15);
              }

              else{
                var dir_r_name = dir_name;
              }
         });
        }
       }
```

Here when i work on `substr()` it throws the error `Cannot read property 'val' of undefined`. I can see this is because the `substr()` is executed before the ajax request is completed. how do i fix this ?

**EDITED**

Here is the response

```
{"msg":"1","director":{"dir_name":"Naveen","dir_pan":"AAAAA1111B","dir_din":"123456","dir_addr":"dsadasdasdasdsadasdas","dir_img":"1490852438.jpg","user_id":3,"updated_at":"2017-03-30 05:40:38","created_at":"2017-03-30 05:40:38","id":15}}
```

Comment: Everything has to happen inside the `success` method.

Comment: What is the value of 'data' response?

Comment: it has json response.

Comment: Another way around this is, is to create a function as a wrapper to your logic and pass in the response object from the success in the function as parameter. You can then use this function in the success.

Comment: How does `value.dir_name` have a `.val()` method? That would have to be a jQuery Element. I'm doubting that, unless that is some strange data.

Comment: Please share your 'data' value completely. How you are iterating and what objects are available in that. There is an issue with it.

Comment: @Nitesh response data is added to the question

Comment: have you tried with a `promise`?

Comment: can you explain why you use $.each, whats your purpose? are there several directors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear why you use the `$.each` here (you can omit it and use `data.director` instead of `value`), but if it is possible that your data contain several 'director' objects and you want to iterate through all of them, then you should change the `insertDirector` code to skip the 'msg' key as it doesn't have `dir_name, dir_plan, ...` properties:

```
function insertDirector(data) {
  console.log(data);
  if (data.msg == "1") {
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
      if (key == "director") { //or if (key != "msg")
        var dir_name = value.dir_name;
        var dir_pan = value.dir_pan;
        var dir_din = value.dir_din;
        var dir_addr = value.dir_addr;
        var dir_id = value.id;
        var dir_img = value.dir_img;

        var dir_r_name = (dir_name.length > 15 ? dir_name.substr(0, 15) : dir_name);
        //if (dir_name.length > 15) {
        //  var dir_r_name = dir_name.substr(0, 15);
        //}
        //else {
        //  var dir_r_name = dir_name;
        //}
      }
    });
  }
}
```

also, note that `dir_name.val().length` is wrong as dir_name is a string (`.val()` is not required)

Comment: About to write this as own answer. This is what i exactly did.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if (dir_name.val().length > 15) {
  var dir_r_name = dir_name.substr(0,15);
}
```

to

```
if (dir_name.length > 15) {
  var dir_r_name = dir_name.substr(0,15);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
function insertDirector(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.msg == "1") {

        var dir_name = data.director.dir_name;
        var dir_pan = data.director.dir_pan;
        var dir_din = data.director.dir_din;
        var dir_addr = data.director.dir_addr;
        var dir_id = data.director.id;
        var dir_img = data.director.dir_img;

        if (dir_name.length > 15) {
            var dir_r_name = dir_name.substr(0, 15);
        }

        else {
            var dir_r_name = dir_name;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: About to write this as own answer. This is what i exactly did.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the data you posted, it is easy to find issue.
Here, the issue is:

Your function:

```
function insertDirector(data){
      console.log(data);
      if (data.msg == "1") {
        $.each(data,function(key,value){
            var dir_name = value.dir_name;
            var dir_pan = value.dir_pan;
            var dir_din = value.dir_din;
            var dir_addr = value.dir_addr;
            var dir_id = value.id;
            var dir_img = value.dir_img;

              if (dir_name.val().length > 15) {
                var dir_r_name = dir_name.substr(0,15);
              }

              else{
                var dir_r_name = dir_name;
              }
         });
        }
       }
```

Here, when you do $.each, every object inside data will be traversed. Now, your first value inside **data is msg:1. This is not a object**. As a result, on first iteration, *key is 'msg' but value is '1'*. Now this value can't have *dir_name so undefined is returned*. As a result dir_name.val() generates error.

Try it like this:

```
function insertDirector(data){
      console.log(data);
      if (data.msg == "1") {
        $.each(data,function(key,value){
            if(key==="director"){
            var dir_name = value.dir_name;
            var dir_pan = value.dir_pan;
            var dir_din = value.dir_din;
            var dir_addr = value.dir_addr;
            var dir_id = value.id;
            var dir_img = value.dir_img;

              if (dir_name.val().length > 15) {
                var dir_r_name = dir_name.substr(0,15);
              }

              else{
                var dir_r_name = dir_name;
              }
            }

         });
        }
       }
```